# ios swift parse.com: How can I select data from multiple objects?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

`chosenCardSetObjects`is an `NSMutableArray` and holds a set of `PFObjects`.

I would like now to select data for all these given objects.

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Card")
query.includeKey("cardset")

query.whereKey("cardset", equalTo: ???)
```

How can I pass here my `chosenCardSetObjects` holding all objects I want to search for?

`equalTo` can hold a single object, so was looking for something to hold an array and found this:

`query.whereKey("cardset", containsAllObjectsInArray: chosenCardSetObjects)`
As ist says in the docs:

> - (instancetype)whereKey:(NSString *)key containsAllObjectsInArray:(NSArray *)array

But that returns me an error saying that: **[Error]: non supported clause for pointer field cardset**

Just for testing I tried:

```
for objectid in chosenCardSetObjects{
   query.whereKey("cardset", equalTo: objectid)
}
```

Which "works" for the last object in `chosenCardSetObjects`. But that means, my array is OK and filled correct with PFObjects, or not?

So what is the correct way of selecting my data for a list of given PFObjects?
Please advice :)

Comment: The error message states that `cardset` is a pointer to another Parse object. What is that object?

Comment: ups, copy paste error, I need to update my code. I query from class `Card` which has the pointer `cardset` to class `CardSet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `whereKey:containedIn:` I think:

```
query.whereKey("cardset", containedIn: chosenCardSetObjects)
```

This will give records where the pointer is one of the chosen cards.

Comment: Yes, `containedIn` is the right way!

My problem was that I defined the array as
`var chosenCardSetObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()` and this method requires a `NSArray`.